# Decipher This Powershell Code With Me

Tags: powershell, wake-on-lan

I'm working on a Wake-On-Lan script and I have this code that is working I am just trying to understand it better.

Here is an excerpt that I am having trouble with:

```
$mac = "78ab78ab78ab" #some user input mac address reformatted to something like this one
$packet = [byte[]](,0xFF * 102)
6..101 |% { $packet[$_] = $mac[($_%6)] }

[byte[]](,0xFF * 102)
```

This is saying to make an array of byte values `0xFF` 102 times correct? So `packet[0]` should equal `0xFF` through `packet[101] = 0xFF`

```
6..101 |% { $packet[$_] = $mac[($_%6)] }
```

This is a loop that operates on an element of the $packets array we declared earlier based on the iterator `($_)` that grows by one as it progresses through the loop. I'm not sure what the `$_%6` does in particular the `%6` operator. I have ran through the loop and output the value (which does change) but since I'm not familiar with the operator I'm not sure what the output really means.

Comment: Can you format your question a little bit better?

Comment: @rene: I just did that, hope it looks better now.

Comment: Thanks I was in the process of messing with the format the code blocks didn't take the first time around.

Comment: @Neolisk yes much better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main question is around `$_%6`. You should read it as `$_` `%` `6`, where `$_` and `6` are your operands, and `%` in Powershell is a binary [`Mod` operator from VB.NET world](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se0w9esz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). It returns a remainder of integer division. So, for example `5 Mod 2 = 1`.

Comment: Yes that is the most puzzling one to me. Do you know if I'm track with the second line (the assignment to $packet)?